# Spring 3 Interceptor Order

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, interceptor

I have a Spring 3 Web App that implements two interceptors. Im using a config class annotated @Configuration. The code is as follows:

```
    @Override
public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.addInterceptors(registry);
    registry.addInterceptor(homeInterceptor()).addPathPatterns("/");
    registry.addInterceptor(allInterceptor());
}
```

No matter what order I add the interceptors to the registry, the allInterceptor's preHandle function is always called before the homeInterceptor's preHandle. Does anyone know how to control the order that interceptors are invoked?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I looked at the underlying implementation, the global interceptors(not associated to any path mapping) get executed before the mapped interceptors (with associated path patterns). So if you want the `homeInterceptor` to be executed before the `allInterceptor`, the `allInterceptor` may have to be made a mapped interceptor(by providing a path pattern).

These are the two methods that record the interceptors and find the interceptors at runtime:
`org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMapping.initInterceptors()`

`org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMapping.getHandlerExecutionChain(Object, HttpServletRequest)`

Comment: Thank you very much for this answer. I added the pattern "/**" to the allInterceptor and the order works as expected. It's unfortunate that this isn't documented somewhere as it's rather counterintuitive. Well, I'm glad it's at least documented here!

Comment: Unfortunately didn't work for me: regardless of how I put my 2 interceptors (one global and one not, both non-global) I wasn't able to make spring use first one and then the other. I ended up merging the two.

Answer (score 3):

It seems in Spring 3 they have removed the logic that executes the global interceptors first. Now the interceptors are executed in the order in which they are declared.

Note however that the postHandle of the interceptors is executed in REVERSE order!