# Add filter before OAuth2AuthenticationProcessingFilter

Tags: spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

I am using spring-security-oauth2 in IDP mode and spring-boot. I need to do some work before the oauth token is extracted from the request.  How do I add a filter before `OAuth2AuthenticationProcessingFilter`?

I have tried:

```
@Configuration
@EnableResourceServer
public class OAuth2ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http.authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated().and()
                .addFilterBefore(new MyFilter(), OAuth2AuthenticationProcessingFilter.class);
    }

}
```

But I get the following exception:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot register after unregistered Filter class org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.authentication.OAuth2AuthenticationProcessingFilter

I guess this might be because `@EnableResourceServer` is executed after `configure(HttpSecurity http)`.

Comment: Could you add any `interceptor` instead of `filter` ?

Comment: I am using these filters in multiple WebSecurityConfigs.  As long as Interceptors allow this I should be able to use them. I also need to control the order in which the filter runs (TenantFilter runs before JwtFilter which in turn runs before WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter etc.).  I also need to be able to selectively use different Interceptors for different WebSecurityConfigs.  Is this possible with Interceptors? Can you provide an example?

Comment: This may be help for you. https://stackoverflow.com/q/11586757/4423636

Comment: @jax Did you solve this? I have the exact same problem, and it only ends up with anti-patterns and ugly stuff :( I'd like to be able to add a filter, once the filterchain has been created by `@EnableResourceServer`.

Comment: @jax Have you resolve the issue?

Answer (score 6):

I achieved desired functional by doing this

```
                .addFilterBefore(new MyTokenFilter(), AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter.class)
```

Answer (score 2):

The following worked for me

```
   @Override
   public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
       http
         .addFilterBefore(new MyFilter(), AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter.class)
         .authorizeRequests().anyRequest().fullyAuthenticated()
       ;
   }
```

Result

```
Security filter chain: [
  WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter
  SecurityContextPersistenceFilter
  HeaderWriterFilter
  LogoutFilter
  MyFilter
  OAuth2AuthenticationProcessingFilter
  RequestCacheAwareFilter
  SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter
  AnonymousAuthenticationFilter
  SessionManagementFilter
  ExceptionTranslationFilter
  FilterSecurityInterceptor
]
```